# What would be the quickest/most pythonic way of removing all rows in a dataframe that are also in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For now I've got it this way:

```
dfA = dfA[dfA.names.isin(dfB.names) == False]
```

Edit: I'm checking to see if the value of a specific column - "names", is the same in dfA & dfB. If yes, I would like to remove that entire row from dfA.

Is there something quicker than this? I'm dealing with a large amount of data and would like to reduce execution time as much as possible.

Example -

```
dfA:
names phone_no
A      123
B      456 
C      789
```

dfB:

```
names blah
A      sgsg
C      dfgd
```

Result:

```
names phone_no
B      456
```

Comment: The title says rows but you are checking the columns. Is this a square matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try add `~` for inverting mask instead `== False`:

```
dfA = dfA[~dfA.columns.isin(dfB)]
```

Comment: Not sure if that is adding anything speed-wise, but that works too. Thanks!